# What is the difference between Insights metrics page_engaged_users and page_consumptions_unique?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

There are two very similar Page-oriented Insights metrics:

- `page_engaged_users` - "The number of people who engaged with your Page. Engagement includes any click"
- `page_consumptions_unique` - "The number of people who clicked on any of your content"

([source](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/insights#metrics))

Clearly, I can see that they are different, but the definitions are vague.  Using plain language (even a simple example), please explain what the difference is between these two metrics.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best I can find so far:

> The main difference between how Consumers and Engaged Users are
>   defined, is that Consumers are people that clicked on your posts
>   (anywhere within a post), while Engaged Users are people that clicked
>   or created a story anywhere on your page (this includes liking your
>   page).
>
> Since Consumer engagement is limited to posts and Engaged Users
>   can click anywhere on the page, the number of Engaged Users on your
>   page will always be equal to or larger than the number of Consumers.
>
> Both metrics are available within Facebook Insights at the page and
>   post level. At the post level the number of Engaged Users and
>   Consumers should almost be equal.

Source: http://simplymeasured.com/blog/2013/09/11/facebook-metrics-defined-consumers-vs-engaged-users/

Comment: 2015 Update: See also http://brnrd.me/engagement-vs-consumption-the-facebook-dilemma/